# Asignación nueva cookie

Tags: apache, cookies

desde Apache necesito que cuando autentica un usuario,  invalidar la sesión de la petición y cargarla en una nueva cookie.

Hola a todos, tras un análisis de seguridad de una aplicación se ha encontrado que es vulnerable a que un atacante puede asignar una cookie de sesión que él conoce a una victima y esperar a que esta se autentique con ella. Si esta cookie de sesión no cambia después de la autenticación, el atacante tendrá en su poder una cookie de sesión de otro usuario sin saber sus credenciales.

Para evitar esto necesito que tras la autenticación se asigne una nueva cookie a esa sesión, invalidando la anterior.

No tengo nada claro cómo hacerlo, alguien podría ayudarme. Utilizo Apache 2.4

Comment: Que tal Valentin!!! Pregunta, autentica para que. Un programa?

Comment: Hola José Miguel. Es una aplicación Java, es la autenticación del usuario en esa aplicación web para hacer uso de la misma. La aplicación correo sobre un Jboss y delante está el Apache, tal y como comentaba antes.

Comment: Pues quien debe asignar y reasignar una cookie entonces es el mismo Java, el es el controlador. Apache solo es un servidor, que te ayuda a que Java se pueda ejecutar. Busca el código con la cookie en el aplicación Java primeramente